# Why do I get "ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII" in ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I have some code that handles a web request that comes in (not a rails app), and with the following couple lines,

```
str.encode!(::Encoding::ASCII, :undef => :replace, :invalid => :replace, :replace => '')
str.gsub(/[\\\%\']/, '')
```

the `str.gsub` call gets the exception `"ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII"`.

I was under the impression that, if I called the `encode!` method with `::Encoding::ASCII`, it would handle this, but apparently not; the character I'm trying to handle shows up in my text logfile as `‘` or `%91`. Anyone know why the `encode!` call doesn't do what I expect it to?

I don't know what the string looks like exactly beforehand -- this has only ever occurred in a production environment, and I am debugging from logfiles, where the value has likely been encoded in some fashion other than the original.  I'm going to try Marshal.dump'ing the object to save it off and reproduce it locally next time it happens.

Comment: What does `str` look like before the `gsub` call?

Comment: Your code works for me using Ruby 2.1 and `‘` as the string. Perhaps your error is elsewhere?

Comment: well my code works for me using Ruby 2.0 and ‘ as the string also.  The exception definitely occurs on the gsub, and the last thing that happens before the gsub is the encode.  This isn't something I can reproduce -- it occurs every once in awhile in production, but never in dev -- I'm not sure what the exact character being passed in is -- by the time it makes it into my logfile, it has been encoded into something other than what it was when it was in ruby.  I'm going to look at Marshalling it and saving off that as part of an extra log so I can then hopefully see the original version. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Ruby 2.0 (and earlier), trying to use `encode` (or `encode!`) on a string that is already in the target encoding is a no-op](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-encode):

> Please note that conversion from an encoding `enc` to the same encoding `enc` is a no-op, i.e. the receiver is returned without any changes, and no exceptions are raised, even if there are invalid bytes.

In your case, if `str` is already has ASCII encoding then the `encode` call will not do anything, so any invalid bytes will remain and cause errors in the subsequent `gsub` call.

This doesn’t happen with Ruby 2.1, which also introduced the [`scrub` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-scrub) as an easier way to remove invalid bytes.

If you cannot upgrade your version of Ruby you might be able to get round this by changing to a different encoding and back, for example:

```
str.encode(::Encoding::UTF_8, :undef => :replace, :invalid => :replace, :replace => '').encode(::Encoding::ASCII)
```

A better solution would be to ensure you correctly handle the character encoding of all text data entering your application, converting as necessary as it enters (usually to UTF8). How you do this will depend on where the data is coming from.

In your example, it looks like the data is being submitted in the [CP-1252 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (the character `U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` is encoded with the byte `0x91` in that encoding). If you are sure the data always come in this encoding, you could fix this with:

```
str.force_encoding(Encoding::Windows_1252).encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
```